# C++ remembering pointers to allocated strings

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I have this problem in C++ that I cant figure out how to remember pointers to the new allocated strings
in function getName() I create a copy of the wanted name so that the user cant get pointer to the real allocated name..But I cant find a way to free these allocated copies!
is there any other way than Lists? or Array?
thank you

this is the definition of the member function getName();

```
char * Course::getName() const
{
    char* CourseNameCopy= new char*(strlen(CourseName)+1);
    return CourseNameCopy;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant code where you do the copy?

Comment: Unless you are paid by the symbol, do not use meaningless comments in the style of `++i; // increment i`. In your case, your *abstract* and *return value* are the same string, and *Function* is just the repetition of the function name.

Comment: Straight forward solution: `1` Remove `#include <string.h>` `2` Add `#include <string>` `3` Visit [Strings library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string).

Comment: If you return a pointer from `malloc` or `strdup`  or `new` you have no guarantee it will ever get freed. You might change the function to accept a buffer to copy into: `char* getName(char *buffer, size_t bufferLength) const;` Another option is to use `std::string`.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_COURSE_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - Why would one use `malloc` and `strdup` in C++ code?

Comment: @StillLearning I edit the post

Comment: Most of the code here has nothing to do with the question. Remove the irrelevant stuff, including **just about all** of the comments, which are almost entirely noise.

Comment: @SijaanHallak - Perhaps read up about `std::string` would be a good idea

Comment: @EdHeal At th time OP had posted no code for the function. I just used those as examples. Code that was posted  used `char *`.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Perhaps being a bit harsh by deleting the declaration of `CourseName`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - You avoid those functions in C++ code

Comment: @Rabbid76 this will guarantee that the user won't mess with the original name?thanks for replying

Comment: @EdHeal - I didn't touch the code.

Comment: @EdHeal Im new to C++.. Would just explaing to me what is std::string? is it a class that I can use?
thanks

Comment: Please google it - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string - When at that web site perhaps have a look into smart pointers - `shared_ptr`

Comment: @EdHeal This page about basic_string is waaay too complicated for a beginner. It'll only scare him away. @SijaanHallak Just treat `std::string` like a regular type, like an int or double, just for characters, and it's safe. It actually comes from the standard library (add `#include <string>`) and it's a class, yes. You can use it like any "normal" type, e.g. `std::string s("Hello!");` or `std::string s = "Hello!";`. Don't use `new` and `delete` in your C++ code, especially not as beginner.

Comment: @Ela782 - That is being unfair on the poster

Comment: @EdHeal No, it's not meant negative. But if you read his question, _Im new to C++.. Would just explaing to me what is std::string? is it a class that I can use?_, he is very clearly a beginner-beginner. cppreference is awesome, but that page about basic_string is just not suited for _any_ beginner! Not in the least!

Comment: @Ela782 - I think you can point people in the right direction. They may need some time to digest the information. But it is better to show them the book and let them come back to it later

Comment: @EdHeal I definitely agree. But that basic_string page is really horrible for a beginner - heck even for somebody with a couple years of experience. And it doesn't even have example code. If it was something like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), with a short description and nice example code, I would deem that much more useful.

Comment: Perhaps this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ is more palatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::string`, unless you have a very specific reason not to. Your code looks like a prime example for a string.

```
#include <string>

std::string Course::getName() const
{
    return CourseName; // This will return a copy
}
```

Of course you have to change your member variable to be also a `std::string CourseName;`.

This will make your code much safer and much easier to read. It's the preferred way of doing it in C++, unless you're not a beginner anymore and have a very specific reason not to.

Comment: Im not allowed to use it!
Although I'll be using it for myself :D
Thanks!

Comment: And another question: who frees this returned copy?

Comment: @SijaanHallak That's really sad. Send [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) to your teacher or mentor (I'm assuming you are being educated in C++ at a course/company or so).
The returned copy gets freed as soon as it leaves its scope. When it leaves the scope (i.e. on the next following `}`), the destructor of the `std::string` will be called, which will delete the memory. That technique is called [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: Im studying at the Technion Institute of Technology. (Its ranked very high amongst other faculties in EE and CS). The reason they dont teach us these things because of that they need us to find solutions in the ways they want

Comment: We get to learn ADT'S DATA STRUCTURES and Algorithem, C++, and bash in just 3 months

Answer (score 2):

```
char * Course::getName() const
{
    char* CourseNameCopy= new char[strlen(CourseName)+1];
    strcpy(CourseNameCopy, CourseName);
    return CourseNameCopy;
}
```

I've made a couple of corrections to the original code so that it does what it claims to do.

If there's a requirement to return a pointer to a modifiable character array containing a copy of the course name, then this is the way to go. But that's very unusual requirement; usually it's sufficient to return a pointer to a non-modifiable character array, and for that, the internal array is all that's needed:

```
const char * Course::getName() const
{
    return CourseName;
}
```

With that, users can look at the name of the course but not change it. If for some reason someone needs to fiddle with the returned text they can make their own copy and change that.

Comment: `char* CourseNameCopy= new char*[strlen(CourseName)+1];` - should this be `char* CourseNameCopy= new char[strlen(CourseName)+1];` to have the correct types? (and size for that matter)

Comment: @EdHeal - whoops, of course it should be. Careless copy and paste. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks alot!
I will be using the second solution you suggested.
You saved me alot of time!

Answer (score 0):

> ... so that the user cant get pointer to the ***real allocated name*** ...

You have a slight misconception here. The client (user) doesn't need to have access to the ***name***, just receiving the pointer value (address), is enough to delete it later. Thus clients just have to do the following:

```
Course c("XYZ");

char* n = c.getName();

// deallocate after use
delete[] n;
```

---

Also note you missed to copy the contents actually:

```
char * Course::getName() const {
    char* CourseNameCopy= new char*(strlen(CourseName)+1);
    strcpy(CourseNameCopy,CourseName); // <<<<<<<<<
    return CourseNameCopy;
}
```

---

I have to mention that's not a good solution, because it puts your code's clients in charge to take care about memory management.

Better use a `std::string` member variable for `CourseName`, that was designed for such and takes care about all of the memory management under the hood.

Comment: Should that be `delete[] n`?

Comment: @EdHeal Yup, will fix in a second.